# Combine 2 for loops into one loop (Iterating objects)

Tags: python-3.x, loops, oop

So I am writing a very basic card game with 2 players each having a deck of cards. Each card(object) has health points and damage points. During "fight" each player has to deal damage to the enemy (iterating thru each card in his card deck) and then its the other players turn. Here is the code for the fight:

```
from project.player.player import Player


class BattleField:

    @staticmethod
    def fight(attacker: Player, enemy: Player):
        for x in (attacker, enemy):
            if x.is_dead:
                raise ValueError("Player is dead!")
            if x.__class__.__name__ == 'Beginner':
                x.health += 40
                for card in x.card_repository.cards:
                    card.damage_points += 30
            health_bonus = sum(card.health_points for card in x.card_repository.cards)
            x.health += health_bonus

        for card in attacker.card_repository.cards:
            enemy.health -= card.damage_points
            if enemy.is_dead:
                raise ValueError("Player is dead!")

        for card in enemy.card_repository.cards:
            attacker.health -= card.damage_points
            if attacker.is_dead:
                raise ValueError("Player is dead!")
```

My question is - can these 2 for loops(for dealing damage) be merged in one loop and how. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new method and call it twice:

```
@staticmethod
def iterate_cards(attacker, enemy):
    for card in attacker.card_repository.cards:
        enemy.health -= card.damage_points
        if enemy.is_dead:
            raise ValueError("Player is dead!")
```

And in your `fight` method:

```
def fight(self, attacker: Player, enemy: Player):
    ...
    self.iterate_cards(attacker, enemy)
    self.iterate_cards(enemy, attacker)
```